# Set Facebook wordpress plugin fields while using wp-insert-post

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, custom-fields, codex

I am using wp-insert-post to create posts dynamically in wordpress. The script is in an external file and I have included the wp-load.php file to make use of the wordpress functions there. My query is that while using the wp-insert-post function, we can make use of the default parameters, but how can we include the parameters that are used by the plugin (Facebook, in this case).

I wish to set this parameter: facebook_page_message_box_message

I tried using:

```
$post = array();
$post['post_type']     = 'post'; 
$post['post_title']    = 'Custom title';
$post['post_content']  = 'Custom content';
$post['post_author']   = '1';
$post['facebook_page_message_box_message'] = 'Custom Title (to be displayed on the Facebook timeline, when the post is published)';

$post_id = wp-insert-post($post);
```

But this is not working. I also tried using wordpress functions like,
Wp_set_object_terms, but even that didn't work.

Comment: The wp-insert-post uses default parameters, why dont you try `add_post_meta`

Comment: @VidyaNair I tried using add_post_meta. But that too, didn't work. That's because perhaps, it is used to add 'custom' meta data to a post. What I need here is to set the data which has been used by the Facebook plugin itself.

Comment: you can get the post meta by post id and pass that info

Comment: Did that work? any solution here?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/facebookarchive/wordpress/blob/master/admin/social-publisher/publish-box-page.php

The following links may provide additional information